# viml: get list of all ctags

Tags: vim, ctags

Is there a way to get a viml list of all the tags defined in the tags files?

Right now I'm doing this:

```
let alltags = split(system('cut -f1 tags | tail +7 | uniq'), "\n")
```

which works for me (i.e. only one tags file, generated by exuberant ctags) but feels very brittle. Is there a way to ask vim for this list instead? For example, if I wanted to get a list of all the files that vim remembers, I could use `v:oldfiles` instead of digging through the .viminfo file directly. Is there something similar for tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `taglist()` to query the tag files. See `:h taglist(` for mor information.

Answer (score 2):

```
:tselect /<CR>
```

shows all the tags included in your `tags` file(s) in an actionable list.

If you want to work with that list in vimscript, use `:help taglist()`:

```
:let foo = taglist("/*")
```

Comment: This works, but seems to be quite a bit slower than my initial try when there are a large number of tags.